# Data validation in Google Cloud - BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to validate the data that is exported from Y42 to BigQuery in Google Cloud (e.g. given a predefined schema, I want to check whether all columns appear in the data, the ranges of the values, etc.).

1. I created a Python script that validates the data that comes in a CSV file. However, I do not know how to run the script before exporting the data to Google Cloud. I can create a VM instance in Google Cloud and run a Python script there, but I don't know how to use the data that is stored in Google Cloud in my script. Can anyone give me any hints regarding this issue?
2. I investigated whether there are any other ways to validate data directly in Google Cloud, but I did not find anything. Is someone aware of any data validation methods in Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do, I import the data in BigQuery (in a temporary table to not break my clean prod table) and I run a query on it. That query perform all the checks that I want.

If the query return lines, those lines are in error, the others are OK. Then I merge the valid data in the clean prod table, and the bad data in a log table for further analysis.

All that sequence is orchestrated with [Cloud Workflow](https://cloud.google.com/workflows).

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud released [DVT](https://pypi.org/project/google-pso-data-validator/) as an open source Python CLI tool which automates your validation checks.
The standard output for DVT is printed on terminal but it can be directed to BQ as well where you could dump your results.
As mentionned by Guillaume, Cloud Workflow can help you to orchestrate other tasks and/or actions.